# Pure CSS Slideshow with animation delay fadein fadeout effects

Tags: html, css, slideshow, css-animations

I have this pure CSS slideshow working in "auto-play": [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Dfpt/1/).
I would like to make the transition of this slideshow to work with buttons, only with CSS, with this HTML:

```
   <label for="button-4" class="button-label-4"></label>
   <label for="button-1" class="sp-arrow sp-a1"></label>
   <label for="button-2" class="sp-arrow sp-a2"></label>
   <label for="button-3" class="sp-arrow sp-a3"></label>
   <label for="button-4" class="sp-arrow sp-a4"></label>

   <ul class="cb-slideshow">
      <li>
         <span>Image 01</span>
         <div>
            <p class="text_products">Some Text</p>
         </div>
      </li>
      <li>
         <span>Image 02</span>
         <div>
            <p class="text_products">Some Text</p>
         </div>
      </li>
      <li>
         <span>Image 03</span>
         <div>
            <p class="text_products">Some Text</p>
         </div>
      </li>
      <li>
         <span>Image 04</span>
         <div>
            <p class="text_products">Some Text</p>
         </div>
      </li>
   </ul>
```

do you know how I could do? I've tried but is doesn't work.

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Dfpt/1/) for css.

Comment: you could use tabindex + pseudo element to draw arrows basicly : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/akIht

Comment: Go for this - http://www.creativejuiz.fr/trytotry/juizy-slideshow-full-css3-html5/#sl_i3

Comment: @PravinVaichal the thing is **the fade in/out effect wanted** , wich is simply added to my basic example with a transition on opacity http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/qHFbv/ tabindex set on images can be set on div or figure and get anysize. the method has to remain , but the style is up to your imagination :) Your example could even be run witout animation, just transition : http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/vqkgf , but it was not the question :)

Comment: Ok, I know these examples, they all are with normal transition made with use of margin rules. Not like mine who also has two "slides" showing at same time, with two differents effects. <span> with an image and a <div> with text.

Comment: okay, i'm lost , you show a part of HTMl and link to a slider much more complexe . so his this what you looked for http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/CJpsd/ or is it something else and not just about prev/next arrow ?. there is no probleme of using javascript for sliders :)

Comment: I show the structure and at link you can see what exactly I would like to have. currently is in autoplay, I would like to have the same slideshow working with buttons in pure CSS.

Comment: GCyrillus your codepen works fine but I need to have "Some Text" <div> to work like my jsfiddle, it needs to be shown just after his parent element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've updated the code and now slideshow works with buttons: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lizardhr/qBQz4/2/)

I've removed call for `animation: imageAnimation 24s linear infinite 0s;` on `<span>` elements(slide show background images) and on `.cb-slideshow li div` where some text is shown with different timing respect his background. Now I have the slide show with auto play(who doesn't work correctly) and manual transition by the buttons, who works fine like I would've in my question.